# How print the result of CvMat matrix?

Tags: opencv

Here's how my code looks like:

```
// 10 rows and 2 cols matrix.
CvMat* results = cvCreateMat(10, 2, CV_32FC1);

// Some operations ...

ann->predict(samples, results);

// How to print out the **results** ?
```

Is there any C++ API for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi here is mine to be used for viewing inside data of CvMat.

```
void printMat(CvMat* mat, char* filename)
{
    FILE *pf =fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(pf,"(%dx%d)\n",mat->cols,mat->rows);
    for(int i=0; i<mat->rows; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<mat->cols; j++)  fprintf(pf,"%10d",j+1);
        }

        fprintf(pf,"\n%4d: ",i+1);
        for(int j=0; j<mat->cols; j++)
        {

            fprintf(pf,"%10.2f",cvGet2D(mat,i,j).val[0]);
        }
    }
    fflush(pf);
    fclose(pf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What works is `std::cout << cv::Mat(results) << '\n';`

This is since `cv::Mat` can be [constructed](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp#L1717) from `CvMat` and `cv::Mat` has operator `<<` [overloaded](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L3869).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << results <<"\n";
```

As an extra bonus this prints in a format that can be copied straight into matlab

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV 3, `cv::Mat(results)` does not work anymore (at least since OpenCV 3.2, the version I used).

Instead, you should use [cvarrToMat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dd7/group__core__c__glue.html#gafa8ade391d84ed9278c336fd0a58f4e1):

`std::cout << cv::cvarrToMat(results) << '\n';`